# RavenDB DocumentStore in Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, ravendb

I was following a tutorial on how to use RavenDB with ASP.Net, and it says to put the creation of the Document Store in the global.asax, so it is created once on application load.

I wanted to make my ASP.Net application so it can use any database, so I had planned to move the data access layer into a class library. The problem now is I don't know how I should access the RavenDB.

I know I can't create a new instance each time, so how would I do it? I realise I can pass in the instance of the RavenDB, but doing that would mean RavenDB would still be within the application itself, which I had hoped to avoid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe creating a generic HelperClass that reads some config file, and then initialize RavenDB at app_start if its parametrized for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reference RavenDB from the class library, you can't really go around that. You may find the following article insightful, though: http://novuscraft.com/blog/ravendb-and-the-repository-pattern

Comment: Thanks. It definitely gives me more to go on.